# Run bitbucket pipeline only on PR creations but not on updates

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket allows to start pipeline for a PR:

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "First step"
```

And this pipeline runs on both PR creations and updates. Every single push to a branch for this PR reruns it.

Is there a way to run a pipeline only on PR creations but not on updates?

Comment: Please rephrase the title of the question so it summarizes your question. This field is not a tag but a headline, it should contain the core idea of the question asked so that someone else could related to this question in the future. "Bitbucket pipeline" is utterly vague.

Comment: I don't think that's possible but... Why would you want that? What if someone breaks the build in a PR update?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed the title of the topic for a more suitable name.

Comment: I need it for saving snapshots in one of the UI libraries.
We have a step that builds and publishes a component library. And we have a monthly posting limit.
Therefore, every time we create a Pull Request, we need to publish this library and if something went wrong, then fix it and publish it again manually by custom pipeline. And if everything was assembled correctly the first time, then we don’t need to publish it again with each commit to this branch.

Comment: With little knowledge about that workflow, my first thought would be to move such step to a pipeline run from the main integration branch and not from PRs. Either from a "branch" pipeline that runs on every merged PR or from a daily-scheduled custom pipeline.